# Blender UV Help

Tags: mesh, uv

Hi I've got a blend here: [image]

It has UV's, but only visible when selecting each object in edit mode. Each UV seems to be going to a different UV Map.

Could someone guide me on where to go next in my blend to create the simple UV?

Setting the alpha on the UV or texture (set it to background) is one of the troubles.

Comment: Please include a screen snapshot so that others may get a better idea of your specific problem at a glance, in addition to your blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object will have it's own UV Map. The UV Map is how the texture is mapped to the vertices. So, you need one UV Map per Object.

If you want to view UVMaps for all 4 cushions, you have some options:

1. You can join the cushions into one object (select all the objects in Object Mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). Then, you can just resize the current  UVMaps to fit on the texture.
2. There is a 'Show Other Objects' option in UV Editor -> View.  This only works if you have multiple objects selected, and they are using the same texture. With multiple objects selected, you can still tab over to edit mode. but you are only modifying the active object. (the active object is the last object selected)

[image: screenshot]

The UVMap outlines are light grey and hard to see. But, with 3 cushions selected, if you look closely, you can see all the overlapping islands in the texture window.

hopefully this helps some.